# Php image doesn't show

Tags: php, mysql

Why the following php script doesn't show the image. I checked that database connection is OK and Mysql Query is also Ok.

**Php Code:**

```
$upload_directory = "uploaded"; //set upload directory

$getimages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property_step3 WHERE propertyid =  
'$propertyid' AND active =1 AND uname = '$uname'"); 

$re2 = mysql_fetch_array($getimages)
$images = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re2['imgname'])));


echo '<img src="$upload_directory/$images" width="98" height="68"  /></a>';
```

May be I'm wrong..

**I don't understand why are some people are voting me DOWN ??!!**

Update:

```
<?php
 $uname = $_SESSION['uname'];
 $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property_step1 WHERE uname = '$uname' AND active 
 = 1");
 $num = mysql_num_rows($check);

if($num == 0)
{

echo "<h3>You didn't upload any property. Click <a href='publishadvert.php'>here</a> 
to publish your property</h3>";

}
else
{
    echo "<h3>You have $num published property.</h3>";

    echo "<table width='1020' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='tabletr3'><b>Property Title</b></td>";
    echo "<td class='tabletr3'><b>Area</b></td>";
    echo "<td class='tabletr3'><b>State</b></td>";
        echo "<td class='tabletr3'><b>City</b></td>";
    echo "<td class='tabletr3'><b>Country</b></td>";            
    echo "<td class='tabletr3'><b>Images</b></td>";         
    echo "<td class='tabletr3'><b>Action</b></td>";         
    echo "</tr>";

    while($re = mysql_fetch_array($check))
    {
$propertyid = (int) $re['propertyid'];  
$country = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['pro_country'])));
$state = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['pro_state'])));
$area = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['pro_area'])));
$city = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['pro_city'])));
$title = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re['pro_title'])));

 $getimages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property_step3 WHERE propertyid = 
 '$propertyid' AND active =1 AND uname = '$uname'");

    $upload_directory = dirname(__file__) . '/uploaded/'; //set upload directory    
while($re2 = mysql_fetch_array($getimages))
{
$images = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($re2['imgname'])));
}



        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='tabletr2'>$title</td>";
            echo "<td class='tabletr2'>$country</td>";
            echo "<td class='tabletr2'>$state</td>";
            echo "<td class='tabletr2'>$city</td>";
            echo "<td class='tabletr2'>$area</td>";     
                  echo '<img src="'.$upload_directory.'/'.$images.'" width="98" 
 height="68"  /></a>';      

echo "<td class='tabletr2'><img src='uploaded/$images' 
/></td>";                               
echo "<td class='tabletr2'><a href='editproperty.php?propertyid=$propertyid&
uname=$uname'>Edit</a> | <a href='deleteproperty.php?propertyid=$propertyid'>Delete</a>
</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }  
    echo "</table>";

     }
 ?>
```

Comment: can you check page view source and see what is value of `src` image

Comment: Try to check the upload folder permissions, usually it needs to be accessible by anyone (777 in *nix system)

Comment: Don't call mysql_real_escape_string() on output data.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski What should be call, i'm new php.

Comment: @GBD It's show <img src='uploaded/50b11aefaad43font-8.jpg' />

Comment: @Shibbir `mysql_real_escape_string()` is only for input values into the database.

Comment: what is the value of $re2['imgname']; after statement $re2 = mysql_fetch_array($getimages);

Comment: @djakapm It's on my Localhost Server.

Comment: Try to browse your image through your browsers

Comment: what is the live actual path of your of your image, and what is the url you are using to access your php file

Comment: its is 404 problem, your path to image is wrong or no image exists

Comment: I haven't voted your Q down but are you voting down answers that don't work for you? Someone is.

Comment: Show us the directory hierarchy of your document root...Please consider before you down vote a question, comment or answer.

Comment: Please print_r($re2) and show us the result.

Comment: And tell us what the error you getting is. Is it blank? Is there HTML? What is that HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistake 1**: What Waqar Alamgir said, but more explicitly. Trying to use variables in single quotes.

```
echo '<img src="$upload_directory/$images" width="98" height="68"  /></a>';
```

will output

```
<img src="$upload_directory/$images" width="98" height="68"  /></a>
```

whereas

```
echo "<img src=\"$upload_directory/$images\" width=\"98\" height=\"68\"  /></a>";
```

or

```
echo '<img src="'. $upload_directory . '/' . $images .'" width="98" height="68"  /></a>';
```

or

```
echo '<img src="', $upload_directory, '/', $images, '" width="98" height="68"  /></a>';
```

will output

```
<img src="uploaded/theimagename.jpg" width="98" height="68"  /></a>
```

where `$images` equals `theimagename.jpg`

**Mistake 2:** (Spotted by Pankaj Khairnar)

```
$re2 = mysql_fetch_array($getimages)
```

is missing a semi-colon. This will break your script.

```
$re2 = mysql_fetch_array($getimages);
```

**Mistake 3** (c/o Michael Berkowski)

Don't call mysql_real_escape_string() on output data

Comment: using all the fixes given in these answers to your syntax errors please show your resulting HTML

Comment: ... If the HTML looks right put the src of the image directly into the browser's address bar. Does it appear?

Comment: Well, @popnoodles, I manually upload a picture and see it's source code and click on the link and it's show the image but when i click on the link which come from php it's does show image it's show "Object now found" But Interesting thing is that both tag are same in source code, like: img src="uploaded/50b11aefaa592font-2.jpg" width="100" height="100" />

Comment: So the image doesn't exist or the URI (src) is wrong. Can you get the image to show in the browser by changing the URI?

Comment: ok but that doesn't help us know where the image is, if it exists. Start at `http://localhost` and find that image and also tell us the URL of the page it's supposed to be seen in.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$upload_directory = "uploaded"; //set upload directory
$getimages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property_step3 WHERE propertyid =  
'$propertyid' AND active =1 AND uname = '$uname'"); 

$re2 = mysql_fetch_array($getimages);
$images = trim($re2['imgname']);
echo '<img src="'.$upload_directory.'/' .$images. '" width="98" height="68"  /></a>';
```

also ; at the end is missing on your statement

```
$re2 = mysql_fetch_array($getimages)
```

it should be like this

```
$re2 = mysql_fetch_array($getimages);
```

Comment: can you please send the output of img tag which you are echoing at last line

Answer (score 0):

Problem with quotes you can not use varaibles in single '

```
$upload_directory = "uploaded";
$getimages = mysql_query("SELECT imgname FROM property_step3 WHERE propertyid =  
'$propertyid' AND active =1 AND uname = '$uname'"); 
$re2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getimages)
$images = $re2['imgname'];
echo 'Debug image: ',$images;

echo '<a href="#"><img src="',$upload_directory,'/',$images,'" width="98" height="68"  /></a>';
```

Comment: but now there's a syntax error using commas instead of periods to concat an echo

Comment: its is good to use commas when echoing, PHP doesn't have to make un necessary concatenation

Comment: My bad sorry. Do you know who's voting these answers down?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the full url to make the image shows, like adding

`http://localhost/.../uploaded/50b11aefaad43font-8.jpg`

I am not sure the directory hierarchy on your machine.

I assume that the 'uploaded' folder is inside your htdocs root.

Comment: the problem he has, he used variables in single quote, in echo.

Comment: What I meant is to add the root url like this: `echo '<img src="http://localhost/$upload_directory/$images" width="98" height="68"  /></a>';` It got nothing to do with the echo statement, why down vote?